# how to send output of curl request to 2 separate commands

Tags: bash, command-substitution, gawk

I'm piping the output of a curl request to gawk so that I can pull some data.
The gawk code is already working if I'm searching through the html file which curl request produces. 
However, I was hoping to simply edit in place, as I just need to allocate 2 date variables. I've been looking at using tee and process substitution. 
Is there any way to somehow fork the output of the curl request in order to assign 2 different variables, both using gawk and command substitution.

Here's a snippet of my code, I've hidden the full details of the curl request, but it is going to pull an html report which will contain: Oldest Sequence, date and Newest Sequence, date on separate lines. The gawk has already been tested on the data.

```
curl -k -q "https://user:password@ipaddress/report"
```

I want the output of the above command to be piped or otherwise to the two commands below

```
date1="$(date -d $(gawk '/Newest Sequence/ {print $3,$4}') +%s)"
date2="$(date -d $(gawk '/Oldest Sequence/ {print $3,$4}') +%s)"
```

Is this possible without creating a file? I will be running the request at frequent intervals and sending the result to a socket, I'd rather avoid unnecessary files if possible

Answer (score 4):

The basic syntax you need is this:

```
read date1 date2 < <( curl ... | gawk '...' )
```

This way you need just one `awk` instance as illustrated here (without the seconds conversion which you'd have to add; see below):

```
read date1 date2 < <( curl ... |
    awk '
      /Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }
      /Oldest Sequence/ { old=$3" "$4 }
      END { print new, old }
      '
    )
```

(If the order of the dates in the HTML file is fixed that could be simplified by immediately printing the date information.)

Note that `gawk` has also the necessary time functions so that your `date` based code will become obsolete. In the code I showed you'd need to add awk's `mktime()` calls, or alternatively (to avoid `gawk`'s time functions) do the conversion on shell level with `date` modifying the variables, as in:

```
date1=$(date -d "${date1}" +%s)
date2=$(date -d "${date2}" +%s)
```

Comment: I need to filter the output of of gawk twice to get 2 dates. one from oldest sequence and one from newest sequence.
And yes, I should use the gawk dates, it's that horrible stfrtime function I remember from one of my first c++ assignments, when I didn't know any c at all. Need to read through properly and then could use instead

Comment: No, you just need one pass. I'll add that part to my answer.

Comment: why not use `curl ... | awk ... | read date1 date2` ?

Comment: @Archemar; in `ksh` (e.g.) you can do that, because the final pipe command is performed in the current shell process (and not spawned in a subprocess), but in `bash` - the shell that seems to dominate here - that's not possible; because `date1` and `date2` will in `bash` not be set in the current process you can't simply (without other means) use them after the command. Try `echo a b | read x y ; echo $x $y` once in `ksh` and once in `bash` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thank you. I like the idea of using read and two variables. Off to write the awk date command, and then see how it works. I wonder if I pipe to read, rather than process substitution, will that save a subshell and be a little quicker?

Comment: I have another question, and would really appreciate your experienced input, any of you :)
The two variables will contain dates, in secs, and I'll subtract one from the other. Maybe I could do the whole calculation in gawk, using gawk variables. And then simply output the result into a single bash variable. Would this be best way to do it? I'm looking for maximum efficiency overall
thanks so much everyone!

Comment: @jewro; WRT your first question today: the direct read from pipe approach will not work in `bash` (because of the subshell issue I described). If you can use a `ksh` then I'd go for the read from pipe, just because it's a simpler construct. WRT performance don't worry; in both constructs you have a communication pipe (either explicit or implicit), and the same number of processes.

Comment: @jewro; WRT your second question today: well, in this specific case I think it's a bit simpler to do it in shell (as illustrated in my answer; for the difference just add `diff=$((new-old))`), because in awk you'd have to split the date format from the HTML file to fit the syntax of `awk`'s `mktime()` function, which might get a bit clumsy. Though if you intend to do yet more data processing it may pay to do everthing in `awk`. So it depends. It is certainly a good example to try and enlightening to check out both variants.

Comment: @Janis. Ah, I see. But I can try your suggestion. Great. I'll have a bit more of look at gawk time functions and decide if complexity is worth it or not. Thanks!

Comment: @Janis; I've written the following read based on your suggestion, but both dates are being added to the first variable, even though with the comma between new,old gawk should be outputting these with a space as the OFS. And I would have thought that read would see these as two separate tokens? Any suggestions for how I might fix. Do I need to insert a new line, or set the OFS to something specific?
 dateStrNew dateStrOld < <(curl -k -q   "https://user:password@ipaddress/report" | html2text | gawk '/Newest Sequence/ {new=$3" "$4} /Oldest Sequence/ {old=$3" "$4} END { print new,old }')

Comment: I don't know why a semi-colon is showing after report. It's not actually there

Comment: In the code of your comment I don't see any `read` command used; check that. In the `awk` program the default `OFS` is already a blank, so the `print new, old` should work as expected. (The spurious semicolon must not be there, yes.) To find the bug I suggest to start with the plain syntactical form, and add your commands one by one, so that you can see where the problem is.

Comment: Copy paste error. Should be: read dateStrNew dateStrOld < <(curl -k -q "user:password@ipaddress/report"; | html2text | gawk '/Newest Sequence/ {new=$3" "$4} /Oldest Sequence/ {old=$3" "$4} END { print new,old }')

Comment: Sorry multiple comments as hard to edit from phone. I'm printing out both variables and both dates are being read into the first date variable only. I'm assuming it's IFS or OFS issue, but haven't got to bottom of it yet

Comment: @Janis Thank you so much for your help, I mean it from the bottom my of my heart. This was the last not working for my first software project. Something that was going to be more a hobby project, but turned to the real thing. To say I've been sh*tting myself would be an understatement.
So, finally I got it working, I did need to decompose a bit more, that's where I'd been going wrong. And I realised that the first space in the first date was causing word splitting to read. Eventually I changed the IFS in the shell and the OFS in awk statement (that was fiddly). I nearly wept when it worked!

Comment: IFS=","
read dateStrNew dateStrOld < <(curl -k -q "https://user:password@ipaddress/report" | html2text | gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }')